# "...than..." Vs"...than to..."

Tags: word-usage

Can we say:

> I would rather read a book than **to watch** a movie.

instead of:

> I would rather read a book than **watch** a movie.

I have searched the web and found that it is used without "to". But why is it so? Is the first use incorrect?

Comment: ? Is there a reason you want to insert the "to" there? And if so, why hadn't you inserted it in front of "read a book" to maintain parallel construction between the two verb phrases?

Comment: But to answer your question: yes, the first sentence is incorrect. "Would rather" is one of those phrases that takes [a bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) after it.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Would rather' expresses choice and means 'would prefer to do
>   something'.

So logically your first sentence reads like this:

- I would prefer to read a book than (prefer) to to watch a movie.

The main rule is *"would rather"* + *verb*!

> [**Would rather, would sooner: typical errors**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/would-rather-would-sooner)
>
> We don’t use would rather or would sooner with an -ing form or a
>   to-infinitive:
>
> I don’t need a lift, thanks. I’d rather walk.
>
> Not: I’d rather to walk. or I’d rather walking.
>
> When we use not referring to a different subject, we attach not to the
>   second clause, not to would rather or would sooner:
>
> I’d rather they didn’t tell anyone
>
> Not: I’d rather not they told anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Would rather = would prefer to

'Would rather' is followed by the bare Infinitive :

I would rather read a book than watch a movie.
It means : I would prefer to read a book than to watch a movie.
(Note that the verb 'prefer' is followed by the 'to'-infinitive.)

N.B : I would rather read a book than watch a movie.

= I would sooner read a book than watch a movie.

= I had rather read a book than watch a movie.

= I had sooner read a book than watch a movie.

= I had as soon read a book as watch a movie.

All these are the ways to show preference.

Comment: @phoog, now please have a look at my answer that has been edited right now.